# Magento 2 custom css file include

Tags: magento

I am new in Magento and using the current version of Magento ie. 2.2.0.

I have my custom css file which I need to call in the website but the problem is that I don't know where to keep that css file or how to call that file.

Where do I place the css, and how do I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is able to answer that. See here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html.

Here's an excerpt from it:

> The recommended way to do this is adding an [extending](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html)
>   `default_head_blocks.xml` in your theme, and including the required
>   stylesheets in this file.
>
> Your custom default_head_blocks.xml should be located as follows:
>   `<theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`. To include a
>   CSS file, add the `<css src="<path>/<file>" media="print|<option>"/>`
>   block in `<head>` section in a layout file. `<path>` is specified relative
>   to the theme web directory (/web) For example, the
>   following illustrates how stylesheets are included in the default
>   Blank theme:
>
> `<Magento_Blank_theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
        <css src="css/print.css" media="print" />
    </head>
</page>
```

If you are using the Luma theme, you could edit it directly, but it's best to create your own theme that extends it and add the css there. See here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html.

Comment: Cool, now one more problem I'm facing in this is same with JS and jquery. Where to include and how to call

Comment: `<Magento_Blank_theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/` also shows how to include js files. You need to put your js files in `web/js` and reference them in `requirejs-config.js`. Then it'll be loaded via RequireJS (you won't see a js include in your source).

Comment: Could you please tell me the complete steps of doing this.